# Using Google OAuth 2.0, can you see whether Gmail is actually available?

Tags: google-api, gmail, imap, google-oauth, gmail-imap

In my app, I am accessing Google Mail using [the OAuth 2.0 IMAP scope](https://developers.google.com/gmail/xoauth2_protocol#oauth_20_scopes).
Everything works fine, but apparently Google Apps admins can turn off Gmail completely (which for example happens for @stanford.edu accounts).

If this is the case, the IMAP `AUTHENTICATE XOAUTH2` command fails with the very descriptive error message `NO [AUTHENTICATIONFAILED] Invalid credentials (Failure)`

It seems to me that this error message can appear for different reasons, so is there a way to query Google (having the access token etc.) to see if "Gmail exists"?